# Getting 'The device is not ready' error when using DriveInfo.GetDrives()

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to make a program that looks at all the drives, tries to find a removable one with the name "DOM WORK" and then gets the drive name (like E:) and then prints that. Unfortunately i get this error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIODriveError(String driveName, Int32 errorCode)
   at System.IO.DriveInfo.get_VolumeLabel()
   at WorkSync.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\dominic\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WorkSync\WorkSync\Program.cs:line 19
```

I have tried building the program as an executable and then running it with administrator privileges, which did not work.

Here is my code that i am using:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WorkSync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            string memStickName = "";

            foreach(DriveInfo drive in allDrives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(drive.VolumeLabel);
                if (drive.VolumeLabel == "DOM WORK" && drive.DriveType.ToString() == "removable")
                {
                    memStickName = drive.Name;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(memStickName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that the drive is actually accessible using the [DriveInfo.IsReady](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready.aspx) property.

```
foreach(DriveInfo drive in allDrives)
{
  if (drive.IsReady == true)
  {
     // Check volume name here
  }
}
```